# pyqt.returnPressed conecting to function 2 times,need 1

Tags: python, pyqt

I saw this method of pass information from Main to other windows, and everything works fine on another part of the application.

```
class uch_info(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(uch_info, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_Uch_info()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def displayInfo(self):
        self.show()
class main_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(main_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.uch_info= uch_info()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.tableWidget_uch.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self.open_uch_Window)
        
    def open_uch_Window(self):
        row = self.ui.tableWidget_uch.currentIndex().row()
        users = db.reference('users').get()
        users_list=users.get(list(users.keys())[row])
        self.uch_info.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(partial(self.button, users_list.get('login')))
        self.uch_info.displayInfo()
    def button(self,login):
        print('button clicked,login',login)
```

Here, when you first click on `tableWidget_uch` everything is fine, and the `open_uch_Window` window opens and when the `returnPressed` event is called, it displays only 1 time 1 login.
**output**
button clicked,login dimarom4

but when i click on `tableWidget_uch` and open the `open_uch_Window` window second times, and call the `returnPressed` event, it returns two times 'print('button clicked,login',login)': first from past call with login1 and second from this call with login2

**output**
button clicked,login dimarom4
button clicked,login zayaz

how to make it correct? so that each `returnPressed.connect` connects only once to the `button`

Comment: Please use capitalized names for classes and improve your styling (see the [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)), as your code is really difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I use `self.uch_info.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.disconect()` after `print` in `button`